# Не работает карусель, все делаю правильно т тспользую стандартный код, карусель при нажатии просто подергивается, а не переворачива.... помогите!

Tags: bootstrap, карусель

Document
    


    
      
        
            
                
            
            
                
            
            
                
            
        
        
            
            Previous
        
        
            
            Next

```
    <!-- Включення Bootstrap JS та Popper.js із вказанням атрибута defer -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ztFQpPqIwauQv3z9z4/6D5lZ6yWO1/W8I/U8j+5qByh0D1Y5lFfXhqJ8C0aaMQa6"
            crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Document
    


    
      
        
            
                
            
            
                
            
            
                
            
        
        
            
            Previous
        
        
            
            Next

```
    <!-- Включення Bootstrap JS та Popper.js із вказанням атрибута defer -->
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</div>
```

Comment: это ответ на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Что такое "...Previous Next..." это вроде-бы антонимы.